# When should I do git pull to also keep current changes?

Tags: git, git-merge, pull

I made some changes on my working directory and I run `git pull origin master`. My working directory updated, but I lost my changes *(they were unstaged)*.

Now I want to know, when exactly should I do `git pull` to also keep my own changes?

- Once my changes are unstaged ? *(I hardly think so)*
- Once my changes are staged ?
- Once my changes are commited ?

Comment: For what little it's worth, `git pull` is *not* supposed to overwrite uncommitted work. Historically there have been repeated bugs here (though less frequent with Git 2.x than in the bad old days), so I recommend *avoiding* `git pull` entirely. This is not too hard as `git pull` is a convenience short-cut, meaning: *first run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. The second command defaults to `git merge`. You can just run `git fetch` whenever—this is *always* safe—and run the second command once you *want* the second action. You'll also have a better idea of what Git is doing.

Comment: @torek What's the benefit of `git fetch`? What would be me working directory when I run `git fetch`? Getting the last version from repository without merging it with my current working directory is useful?

Comment: `git fetch` means: *Connect my Git to some other Git, and get commits from them.* That's the first half of what `git pull` does. The *second* half is to somehow mix your work—your commits—with their work, typically using `git merge` or `git rebase`. Both parts are (usually and eventually) required, but you can do many useful things *in between* the two parts, provided you don't use `git pull` to do both without stopping. You can run `git fetch` from anywhere within your repository, since all it means is: *call up some other Git and get commits from them, without affecting anything I've done.*

Comment: In particular, what I like to do is run `git fetch`, then *look at what got fetched* (what new commits, if any, I just added to my collection). That lets me steer my next commands in whatever direction is the most useful.

Comment: *"I like to do is run git fetch, then look at what got fetched ..."*, when you fetch, can you see the fetched data in where? You know, it is not merged with your working directory yet, so where is it located?

Comment: It's in commits. Commits are Git's "unit": they're what keep snapshots, and commits are what you transfer with fetch or push. To view commits, you can use `git log`—but you also need a good mental model of what commits *are* and hence what they do for you. You might want to take a look at the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), which is free on line. (I started [writing a book myself](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf) but it's far from complete and I no longer have much time to work on it.)

Comment: Recommended reading: https://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually avoid doing a `git pull` (or `git pull --rebase`) if I have changes either in my working directory or stage.  Instead, I would make a commit of my work.  If that would not be an option, then I would stash my work, and then do the pull.  When you pull you will typically be making a new commit.  Keep in mind that your current work is relative to the current commit, and not to what the new HEAD of the branch will be after pulling.

Comment: *I would **stash** my work* ... How? By pressing Ctrl + S in your IDE? By `git add .` ? By `git commit -m "<whatever>"`? What does *stash* even mean?

Comment: There is a command `git stash`.  That' it, just type `git stash`.  Git will make 2 (or 3) commits behind the scenes which preserve your working directory and stage.  You'll notice afterward that everything is "clean."  Then, you may `git pull`, and apply the stash afterwards by typing `git stash apply`.

Comment: Just, will I see stashed commit (which are in the behind of the scenes) in the tree diagram? And how many `git stash` can I run before `git stash apply` ?

Comment: No, you won't.  The commit is not part of your current branch.  If you want that, then make a formal commit of your work, which would also clean your stage and working directory.

Comment: «I wasn't aware of that command.» — please, you should definitely start with some [basic education on Git](https://git-scm.com/book/).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you commit your code, before pushing it to branch make a pull request to update your code. So when you'll do this you'll get conflicts at the same moment. This way you can keep your code updated and wont push the effected code by conflicts.

Comment: No problems always a pleasure.